# How can I find out to which category a matplotlib colormap belongs?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Matplotlib divides their colormaps into different categories, like 'sequential', 'qualitative' and so on. (see [matplotlib Docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html))

Is there an easy (or somewhat easy) way to find out, from a given `matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap` object, whether it is classified as 'qualitative'?

In the Colormap object itself I cannot find any category information.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this information is not stored in the colourmap objects (I looked at [`cm.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/cm.py) and [`_cm.py`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/_cm.py)).

If you like the classification in [the tutorial you link to](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html), you could turn it into a dictionary:

```py
cmap_categories = {
    'Perceptually Uniform Sequential':
        ['viridis', 'plasma', 'inferno', 'magma', 'cividis'],
    'Sequential':
        ['Greys', 'Purples', 'Blues', 'Greens', 'Oranges', 'Reds',
         'YlOrBr', 'YlOrRd', 'OrRd', 'PuRd', 'RdPu', 'BuPu',
         'GnBu', 'PuBu', 'YlGnBu', 'PuBuGn', 'BuGn', 'YlGn'],
    'Sequential (2)':
        ['binary', 'gist_yarg', 'gist_gray', 'gray', 'bone',
         'pink', 'spring', 'summer', 'autumn', 'winter', 'cool',
         'Wistia', 'hot', 'afmhot', 'gist_heat', 'copper'],
    'Diverging':
        ['PiYG', 'PRGn', 'BrBG', 'PuOr', 'RdGy', 'RdBu', 'RdYlBu',
         'RdYlGn', 'Spectral', 'coolwarm', 'bwr', 'seismic'],
    'Cyclic':
        ['twilight', 'twilight_shifted', 'hsv'],
    'Qualitative':
        ['Pastel1', 'Pastel2', 'Paired', 'Accent', 'Dark2',
         'Set1', 'Set2', 'Set3', 'tab10', 'tab20', 'tab20b',
         'tab20c'],
    'Miscellaneous':
        ['flag', 'prism', 'ocean', 'gist_earth', 'terrain',
         'gist_stern', 'gnuplot', 'gnuplot2', 'CMRmap',
         'cubehelix', 'brg', 'gist_rainbow', 'rainbow', 'jet',
         'turbo', 'nipy_spectral', 'gist_ncar']
}
```

Then you could make a lookup table from this by flipping the keys and values:

```py
cmap_lookup = {v: k for k, vs in cmap_categories.items() for v in vs}
```

A Matplotlib colormap at least knows its own name, so you could then look up a category like:

```py
from matplotlib import cm

cmap = cm.viridis
category = cmap_lookup.get(cmap.name)
```

Note that `ListedColormap` doesn't store all the colormaps; it provides a way to make colormaps of your own.

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate and concise suggestion! I was somewhat afraid, that this would be the way to go. The problems I see with this approach are: 
a) it works only for exactly the color maps provided by `cm`, which is no surprise though. 
b) it seems that I would have to keep that dictionary up to date myself, manually, which is a bit saddening. /:
Well then, ... But again, thanks a lot.

Comment: All true. Certain categorizations could be done programmatically, for example, you can recognize qualitative maps from the small number of unique colours; perceptual and diverging colourmaps would be fairly easy to spot from their lightness profiles. So if you only care about one of those categories you could do something more general.